# OPerand mismatch converting from D6 to RS10

Tags: delphi, porting, mismatch, delphi-6, delphi-10-seattle

I took a break from porting code, and now I'm spending some more time on it again.

Problem is, I guess i'm still stuck backwards in my head (everything works fine on D6 :D).

Can anyone tell me why this simple code is not working?

```
if NewSig <> NewCompressionSignature then
```

> E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

Here are the definitions of the above:

```
NewCompressionSignature: TCompressionSignature = 'DRM$IG01';
NewSig: array[0..SizeOf(NewCompressionSignature)-1] of Char;
```

Comment: What product is RS10?

Comment: @RobKennedy: the current version, RAD Studio 10 Seattle.

Comment: Please specify the type of  `TCompressionSignature`!

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing here because the type of `TCompressionSignature` is not given, but I can reproduce `ERROR2015` if  `TCompressionSignature` is declared as some kind of `ShortString` like

```
type
  TCompressionSignature = String[8]
```

As you might know, Delphi is currently using Unicode as its standard internal string encoding. For backward compatibility reasons, the type `ShortString` and other short string types (like `String[8]`) were left unchanged. These strings have the same encoding like `AnsiString` and are composed of standard plain old 1-byte characters (`AnsiChar`).

`NewSig` on the other hand is composed of two-byte Unicode characters and can not be compared directly with an `ShortString`.

One solution of your problem would be to declare:

```
NewSig: array[0..SizeOf(NewCompressionSignature)-1] of AnsiChar;
```

Another solution would be be a cast to string:

```
if NewSig <> String(NewCompressionSignature) then ...
```

But I would prefer to change the array declaration if possible.

Please review the documentation [short strings](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/String_Types_(Delphi)#Short_Strings) and [about unicode](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Unicode_in_RAD_Studio) - especially if you're doing io operations to ensure your input and output is read and written with the correct codepage.